# Need regex replace that only replaces string if not part of a link

Tags: regex-negation

I tried to build a regex that finds a string (a persons name) with another (a link), but only if the found string is not already part of a link.
So it sould replace:

```
Toya with <a href"link">Toya</a>
```

but never:
`<a href="the old link/toya.html">Toya</a>`

because it is a link already.

I tried this

```
(?![^<]*>)Toya
```

but it didnt work as it should.

Any Idea what I can do?

Comment: I think in the general case you might need an HTML/XML parser to handle this.  So I might go for parsing the DOM and then doing a regex replacement on actual _content_.

Comment: Sad, I can't do that in my case. I hoped there was a regex :(